# Dart - merge singly linked list

Tags: dart, linked-list, mergesort

There is some problem in the **mergeSort** method that I couldn't fix.

Singly linked list:
All operations works as expected.

```
class Node {
  /*
   * An object for storing a single node in a linked list
   *
   * Attributes:
   *   data: Data stored in node
   *   nextNode: Reference to the next node in the linked list
   */

  var data;
  Node? nextNode;

  Node(this.data, [this.nextNode]);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '<Node data: $data>';
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  /*
   * Linear data structure that stores values in nodes.
   * The list maintains a reference to the first node, also called head.
   * Each node points to the next node in the list.
   *
   * Attributes:
   *   head: The head node of the list
   */

  Node? head;
  // Maintaining a count attribute allows for length() to be implemented in
  // constant time
  var _count = 0;

  LinkedList();

  bool isEmpty() {
    // Determines if the linked list is empty.
    // Takes O(1) time.

    return head == null;
  }

  int size() {
    Node? current = head;
    int count = 0;

    while (current != null) {
      count++;
      current = current.nextNode;
    }

    return count;
  }

  int get length {
    // Returns the length of the linked list.
    // Takes O(1) time.
     
    return _count;
  }

  void add(dynamic data) {
    /*
      Adds a new Node containing data to the head of the list
      Also called prepend
      Takes O(1) time
    */
    var newNode = Node(data);
    newNode.nextNode = head;
    head = newNode;
    _count++;
  }

  void insert(dynamic data, int index) {
    /*
     * Inserts a new Node containing data at the specified index position.
     * Insertion takes O(1) time but finding the node at the insertion point
     * takes O(n) time.
     * Takes overall O(n) time.
     */

    if (index > _count) {
      throw IndexError.withLength(index, _count, message: 'index out of range');
    }

    if (index == 0) {
      add(data);
      return;
    }
    if (index > 0) {
      var newNode = Node(data);
      var position = index;
      var current = head;

      while (position > 1) {
        current = current?.nextNode!;
        position--;
      }

      var prevNode = current;
      var nextNode = current?.nextNode;

      prevNode?.nextNode = newNode;
      newNode.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    _count++;
  }

  Node? nodeAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= _count) {
      throw IndexError.withLength(index, _count, message: 'index out of range');
    }

    if (index == 0) {
      return head;
    }

    Node? current = head;
    int position = 0;

    while (position < index) {
      current = current?.nextNode;
      position++;
    }

    return current;
  }

  Node? remove(dynamic key) {
    /* Removes Node containing data that matches the key
    Returns the node or `null` if key doesn't exist
    Takes O(n) time */

    Node? current = head;
    Node? previous;
    bool found = false;

    while (current != null && !found) {
      if (current.data == key && current == head) {
        found = true;
        head = current.nextNode;
        _count--;
        return current;
      } else if (current.data == key) {
        found = true;
        previous?.nextNode = current.nextNode;
        _count--;
        return current;
      } else {
        previous = current;
        current = current.nextNode;
      }
    }

    return current;
  }

  Node? removeAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= _count) {
      throw IndexError.withLength(index, _count, message: 'index out of range');
    }

    Node? current = head;

    if (index == 0) {
      head = current?.nextNode;
      _count--;
      return current;
    }

    int position = index;

    while (position > 1) {
      current = current?.nextNode;
      position--;
    }

    Node? prevNode = current;
    current = current?.nextNode;
    Node? nextNode = current?.nextNode;

    prevNode?.nextNode = nextNode;
    _count--;

    return current;
  }

  Node? search(dynamic key) {
    /*
     * Search for the first node containing data that matches the key.
     * Returns the node or `null` if not found.
     * Takes O(n) time.
     */

    var current = head;

    while (current != null) {
      if (current.data == key) {
        return current;
      } else {
        current = current.nextNode;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    // Returns a string representation of the list.
    // Takes O(n) time.
    
    List<String> nodes = [];
    var current = head;

    while (current != null) {
      if (identical(current, head)) {
        nodes.add("[Head: ${current.data}]");
      } else if (current.nextNode == null) {
        nodes.add("[Tail: ${current.data}]");
      } else {
        nodes.add("[${current.data}]");
      }
      current = current.nextNode;
    }
    return nodes.join(' -> ');
  }
}
```

Merge Sort Implementation:

```
import 'linked_list.dart';

LinkedList mergeSort(LinkedList linkedList) {
  /* Sorts a linked list in ascending order
   * - Recursively divide the linked list into sublists containing a single node
   * - Repeatedly merge the sublists to produce sorted sublists until one remains
   *
   * Returns a sorted linked list
   *
   * Takes O(n log n) time
   * Takes O(n) space
   */

  if (linkedList.size() == 1) {
    return linkedList;
  } else if (linkedList.head == null) {
    return linkedList;
  }

  var (leftHalf, rightHalf) = split(linkedList);
  var left = mergeSort(leftHalf);
  var right = mergeSort(rightHalf);

  return merge(left, right);
}

(LinkedList, LinkedList) split(LinkedList linkedList) {
  // Divide the unsorted list at midpoint into sublists
  // Takes O(log n) time

  // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
  if (linkedList == null || linkedList.head == null) {
    LinkedList leftHalf = linkedList;
    LinkedList rightHalf = LinkedList();

    return (leftHalf, rightHalf);
  } else {
    var size = linkedList.size();
    var mid = size ~/ 2;
    var midNode = linkedList.nodeAtIndex(mid - 1);

    var leftHalf = linkedList;
    var rightHalf = LinkedList();
    rightHalf.head = midNode?.nextNode;
    midNode?.nextNode = null;

    return (leftHalf, rightHalf);
  }
}

LinkedList merge(LinkedList left, LinkedList right) {

  /*
   * Merges two linked lists, sorting by data in nodes
   * Returns a new merged list
   * Takes O(n) space
   * Runs in O(n) time
   */
  
  var merged = LinkedList();
  // Add a fake head that is discarded later.
  merged.add(0);
  // Set current to the head of the linked list
  var current = merged.head;

  // Obtain head nodes for left and right linked lists
  var leftHead = left.head;
  var rightHead = right.head;

  // Iterate over left and right as long until the tail node of both left and right
  while (leftHead != null || rightHead != null) {
    // If the head node of left is None, we're at the tail
    // Add the tail node from right to the merged linked list
    if (leftHead == null) {
      current?.nextNode = rightHead;
      // Call next on right to set loop condition to False
      rightHead = rightHead?.nextNode;
    // If the head node of right is None, we're at the tail
    // Add the tail node from left to the merged linked list
    } else if (rightHead == null) {
      current?.nextNode = leftHead;
      // Call next on left to set loop condition to False
      leftHead = leftHead.nextNode;
    } else {
      // Not at either tail node
      // Obtain node data to perform comparison operations
      var leftData = leftHead.data;
      var rightData = rightHead.data;

      // If data on left is lesser than right set current to left node
      // Move left head to next node
      if (leftData < rightData) {
        current?.nextNode = leftHead;
        leftHead = leftHead.nextNode;
      } else {
        // If data on left is greater than right set current to right node
        // Move right head to next node
        current?.nextNode = rightHead;
        rightHead = rightHead.nextNode;
      }
    }
    // Move current to next node
    current = current?.nextNode;
  }

  // Discard fake head and set first merged node as head
  var head = merged.head?.nextNode;
  merged.head = head;

  return merged;
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var l = LinkedList();

  l.add(99);
  l.add(25);
  l.add(3);
  l.add(47);

  print('Unsorted list: $l');

  final sortedList = mergeSort(l);
  print('Sorted list: $sortedList');

  // var r = l.remove(25);
  // print('$r is removed');

  // var n = l.search(99);
  // print('$n is found');

  // int index = 0;
  // var ni = l.nodeAtIndex(index);
  // print('$ni at index $index');

  // var ri = l.removeAtIndex(index);;
  // print('$ri at index $index is removed');
}
```

The **split** and **merge** methods seem to work just fine.

I tried the **split** and **merge** methods separately. They work. Unhandled exception occurs when I call the **mergeSort** method.

**Output:**

```
Unsorted list: [Head: 47] -> [3] -> [25] -> [Tail: 99]

Unhandled exception:
RangeError: index out of range: no indices are valid: 0
#0      LinkedList.nodeAtIndex (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dartpad/bin/linked_list.dart:116:7)
#1      split (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dartpad/bin/merge_sort_linked_list.dart:27:30)
#2      mergeSort (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dartpad/bin/merge_sort_linked_list.dart:10:31)
#3      mergeSort (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dartpad/bin/merge_sort_linked_list.dart:12:15)
#4      main (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dartpad/bin/merge_sort_linked_list.dart:84:22)
#5      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:294:33)
#6      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)

Exited (255).
```

Comment: When you split, you forget to update your internal `_count` variable. So if you split a list with 4 elements, the first list will have a `_count` of 4 and the second a `_count` of 0.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZtS4Gmt . At no point here you update the `_count` variable and the `_count` is not automatically handled by any of the stuff you are doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class LinkedList {
  // ... Existing code ...

  void updateCount(int newCount) {
    _count = newCount;
  }

  // ... Rest of the code ...
}
```

```
(LinkedList, LinkedList) split(LinkedList linkedList) {
  // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
  if (linkedList == null || linkedList.head == null) {
    LinkedList leftHalf = linkedList;
    LinkedList rightHalf = LinkedList();

    return (leftHalf, rightHalf);
  } else {
    var size = linkedList.size();
    var mid = size ~/ 2;
    var midNode = linkedList.nodeAtIndex(mid - 1);

    var leftHalf = linkedList;
    leftHalf.updateCount(mid);

    var rightHalf = LinkedList();
    rightHalf.head = midNode?.nextNode;
    rightHalf.updateCount(size - mid);

    midNode?.nextNode = null;

    return (leftHalf, rightHalf);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).